# jquery - get input name that ends with?

Tags: jquery

My input fields are named like this:

```
<input name="sec[grp-29][factor][0][i_score]" value="4" id="edit-sec-grp-29-factor-0-i-score" type="checkbox" />
<input name="sec[grp-30][factor][0][i_score]" value="4" id="edit-sec-grp-30-factor-0-i-score" type="checkbox" />
<input name="sec[grp-31][factor][0][i_score]" value="4" id="edit-sec-grp-31-factor-0-i-score" type="checkbox" />
```

I'm trying to execute a function baased on whether the checkbox is checked.  As the input fields are created dynamically, I wanted to check for inputs with names that end with "[i_score]".  I tried to do so using:

```
$("input[name$=i-score]]")...
```

But, it doesn't appear to "find" that... Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend, if possible, adding a common class to the inputs instead of referring to it with the contains filter. It is much faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the bracket is a special character, it has to be escaped or quoted. Also, use an underscore instead of the hyphen.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xuXQ5/

```
$("input[name$='i_score]']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the closing square bracket

```
$( "input[name$=i_score\\]]" )
```

In pure css that would be \]], the \ is because JS needs to escape the \ with another \